# How can I convert a character in a string to a number?

Tags: flowgorithm

I am currently making a converter for converting hexadecimals into decimal. When I put a character in console, it says

> "Argument #1 expected a string. It provided an Integer".

I tried using `Char(ToInteger(n))` and `Char(ToCode(n))` but it always returns with

> "Argument #1 expected a string. It provided an Integer".

Please tell me what is lacking or what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to convert a string containing the hexadecimal representation of a number into an integer. You need to work through your string character by character and for every character use the `ToChar()` function. The function wants a string of length 1 and converts the single character into its value in the ASCII table. Example:

[image: example]

This prints

```
48
65
97
```

From here you can work out the other cases.